# Xcode 7/Swift 2 Extra argument 'error' in call

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Extra argument 'error' in call

My Code :

AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)

```
    if NSClassFromString("MPNowPlayingInfoCenter") != nil {
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "albumart")!
        let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
        var songInfo: NSMutableDictionary = [
            MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Radio",
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "fm",
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
        ]
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject]
    }
    if (AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)) {
        print("Receiving remote control events")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    }!
```

[ScreenShot from Xcode (ErrorLog)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ptZ.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The new error handling model is one of the major changes in Swift 2.0 and is documented (for example) in the Xcode 7 release notes and in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html.